# How to implement a K8S proxy watcher api-server?

Tags: kubernetes, watch, kube-apiserver

I need to create a K8S proxy watcher api-server, it receives `list` requests (for some k8s resources) with `watch=true` from clients, and proxy requests to the real upstream K8S API-Server, then receives responses from upstream continuously and send them back.

This is what I did:

1. For server side, original K8S api-server implements `watch` operation using a long-lived HTTP connection, plus chunked response. In code there is a `WatchServer` struct to serve `watch` requests:
   [image]

its first member `Watching` needs an struct implements `watch.Interface` interface. So I have to find a suitable obj to fill this field so that I can implement a similar K8S apiserver.

2. For client side, I have to get real watch events from upstream server, so I used `SharedInformer` in K8S, use add/delete/update event handler to receive up-to-date event notification.

The problem is that `SharedInformer` doesn't implement `watch.Interface` interface, cannot be used to create `WatchServer` struct. So are there any ways to connect these two things together? Or is there any objs that can be used to implement my requirements?